# Retrive first element in the array of the document in mongodb

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

My json sturcture is something like below

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("563872d997e343d8437e30ce"), 

    "bookId" : NumberInt(1), 
    "updateAt" : ISODate("2015-11-03T08:39:53.633+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-11-03T08:39:53.632+0000"), 

    "Images" : [
        {
            "path" : "/opt/bookish/uploads/e11de938d3394622b77f85904a0fbfba.jpg", 
            "contentType" : "image/jpg", 
            "imageName" : "e11de938d3394622b77f85904a0fbfba.jpg", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("563dd28f9305a68548e71f89")
        },
{
            "path" : "/opt/bookish/uploads/e11de938d3394622b77f85904a0fbfba.jpg", 
            "contentType" : "image/jpg", 
            "imageName" : "e11de938d3394622b77f85904a0fbfba.jpg", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("563dd28f9305a68548e71f89")
        },
{
            "path" : "/opt/bookish/uploads/e11de938d3394622b77f85904a0fbfba.jpg", 
            "contentType" : "image/jpg", 
            "imageName" : "e11de938d3394622b77f85904a0fbfba.jpg", 
            "_id" : ObjectId("563dd28f9305a68548e71f89")
        }
    ], 


}
```

here we have a images array how to get only the first image from the array along with bookid

```
Books.find({},'bookId Title Author PublishedDate ShortDesc Images isDeleteBook isPublished',function(err,books){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++");
      console.log(books);
      if(books.Images){
          console.log(books.Images.length);
      }
      res.send(books);
```

Images in the above code will give the entire array rather i need only the first element of the array

Comment: Or basically use [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/). ie `Books.find({},{ "Images": { "$slice": 0 } })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the first image from the array along with `bookId`, you can use the **[`$ projection`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)** operator which projects the array elements based on some condition from the query statement. In your case your query statement will use the dot notation to query for the `Images` array where it has at least an element:

```
Books.find({"Images.0": { "$exists": true} }, {"bookId": 1, "Images.$": 1}, function(err, books){
    if(err)  res.send(err);
    console.log(books);
    res.send(books);
});
```

Alternatively, you may want to go for the **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)** projection operator which controls the number of items of an array that a query returns. In the query below, **[`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)** selects the first item in an array in the `Images` field:

```
Books.find({}, { "bookId": 1, "Images": { "$slice": 1 } }, function(err, books){
    if(err)  res.send(err);
    console.log(books);
    res.send(books);
});
```